# xml SAX parsing doesnt returned the desired result

Tags: java, android

I have an xml provided by my client like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><quizzes updatetimestamp='2012-08-01 06:24'><quiz q_id='1'>
<q_name>Airplane!</q_name >
<q_appleid>com.patelware.moviesquiz.free</q_appleid>
<q_description>"Roger, Roger"</q_description>
<q_urlicon>http://www.inall3.com/king/icons/airplane_icon.png</q_urlicon>
<q_urlmainimg>http://www.inall3.com/king/icons/airplane_main.png</q_urlmainimg>
<q_urldb>http://www.inall3.com/king/dbs/airplane.xml</q_urldb>
<q_timesofupload>2011-05-01 00:00:00</q_timesofupload>
<q_priceindollar>0.00</q_priceindollar>

<q_cattype>Comedy</q_cattype>
<q_thighscore>http://www.inall3.com/hs/highscoreairplane.php?action=gethighscores&amp;mode=1</q_thighscore>
<q_phighscore>http://www.inall3.com/hs/highscoreairplane.php?action=gethighscores&amp;mode=2</q_phighscore>
</quiz>
```

but when I parse it using SAX parser everything is returned correctly but when I try to parse `<q_thighscore>` or `<q_phighscore>` its returning just `mode=1` and `mode=2`, but I want full link to be parsed, where is the problem and what should I do now?

Comment: I assume it has something do with the fact that the `<q_thighscores>` are the only URLs with query strings. Or semicolons.

Comment: Look through some documentation or something? I'm sorry I'm not much help, I don't use parsers.

Comment: Start by posting where you are parsing this.  How are you extracting?

Comment: Are you using sax default handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it and I just used Pull parser instead of SAX parser and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use sax default Handler. See if it works.  If not might need to extend default Handler and override behavior of this method to store the value correctly.  Where myURLString is a variable you define in you extended class.  This variable can then be accessed in endElement method for eample.  you have total control over this here.

So one way is to extend      org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

and override as below

```
   protected String myValueString;


   @Override
   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
   {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);  // deal with escape values here.
            myValueString = ...

    }

then inside   endElement(){


   check if matches your type and if so use myValueString;
```